# Magento Community forum posts not appearing

Tags: untagged

I'm experiencing issues posting to the Magento Community forum. Whenever I post something, it won't get published.

Is anyone experiencing the same? What can the reason be for this?

We contacted Magento support awhile ago but didn't get a response.

Community forum: https://community.magento.com/

Comment: Hi, i think @benmarks can help here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Magento and is not relevant for future visitors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send me an email with your username and associated email. Ben.marks@magento.com.

Comment: I'm in Europe, so I'm several hours ahead of you. We even get tomorrow while it's still today for you. :-D

Comment: Cheers Ben! I'll send you an e-mail with the details now.